# How to group errors at a subform?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Is it possible to have a form group errors at its subform so all errors from elements in the subform are displayed under the subform? At the moment I can do it for the whole form by adding the `FormErrors` decorator to the main form. I have tried this for subforms with both `setSubFormDecorators` and `setDecorators` but no luck.

This doesnt work:

```
$this->setSubFormDecorators(array('ViewHelper','FormErrors'));
```

Any ideas?